# Configure Teamcity bundled with Tomcat servlet container, as a Windows Service

Tags: windows, tomcat, teamcity

I installed Teamcity 2018.1 bundled with Tomcat servlet container on windows 7. I start Teamcity server by running teamcity-server script from bin folder.
But I want to start Teamcity server when windows starts as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple approach to make TeamCity start as a service is to use TeamCity .exe distribution and opt for the service configuration in the installation wizard.

If you are proficient with Windows Services, you can also do that later: use "teamcity-server.bat usage" as a starting point for supported service commands.